# ScheduledExecutorService Is Only Firing Once

Tags: java, timer, scheduled-tasks

I looked at
[ScheduledExecutorService only loops once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379374/scheduledexecutorservice-only-loops-once)

But it doesn't seem to address my issue.

I have a custom timer and when I hit `start` it is supposed to fire a callback every second:

```
/**
 * Starts the timer. If the timer was already running, this call is ignored.
 */
public void start()
{
    if (_isRunning)
    {
        return;
    }

    _isRunning = true;

    // Schedules repeated task that fires each time at the interval given
    Log.d("Timer", "Starting execution");
    _future = _execService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Log.d("Timer", "Fire");

            _elapsedTime += PausableTimer.this._interval;

            // If time has exceeded duration, stop timer
            if (_duration > 0 && _elapsedTime >= _duration)
            {
                Log.d("Timer", "Finish");
                onFinish();
                _future.cancel(false);
            }
        }
    }, 0, _interval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Here is how I invoke the timer:

```
    _timer = new PausableTimer(1000, PausableTimer.DURATION_INFINITY);
    _timer.start();
```

This is creating a timer that fires in 1000 millisecond intervals for inifity.

However my logs only show it firing once. The "Finish" log is not appearing so I know it hasn't ended.

Do you know why this is only firing once?

**Update**

```
/**
 * Timer that can play and pause.
 */
public class PausableTimer extends Timer
{
    public static final int DURATION_INFINITY = -1;

    private Callbacks.VoidCallback _onTick;
    private Callbacks.VoidCallback _onFinish;

    private volatile boolean _isRunning = false;
    private long _interval;
    private long _elapsedTime;
    private long _duration;
    private ScheduledExecutorService _execService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    private Future<?> _future = null;

    /**
     * Creates a pausable timer.
     * @param interval The time gap between each tick in millis.
     * @param duration The period in millis for which the timer should run.
     * Set it to {@code Timer#DURATION_INFINITY} if the timer has to run indefinitely.
     */
    public PausableTimer(long interval, long duration)
    {
        _interval    = interval;
        _duration    = duration;
        _elapsedTime = 0;
        _isRunning   = false;
    }




    /// LIFE CYCLE



    /**
     * Starts the timer. If the timer was already running, this call is ignored.
     */
    public void start()
    {
        if (_isRunning)
        {
            Log.d("Timer", "already started running");
            return;
        }

        _isRunning = true;

        // Schedules repeated task that fires each time at the interval given
        Log.d("Timer", "Starting execution");
        _future = _execService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Log.d("Timer", "Fire");
                onTick();

                _elapsedTime += PausableTimer.this._interval;

                // If time has exceeded duration, stop timer
                if (_duration > 0 && _elapsedTime >= _duration)
                {
                    Log.d("Timer", "Finish");
                    onFinish();
                    _future.cancel(false);
                }
            }
        }, 0, PausableTimer.this._interval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    /**
     * Pauses the timer.
     */
    public void pause()
    {
        if(!_isRunning)
        {
            return;
        }

        _future.cancel(false);
        _isRunning = false;
    }

    /**
     * Resumes the timer if it was paused, else starts the timer.
     */
    public void resume()
    {
        start();
    }

    /**
     * Called periodically with the _interval set as the delay between subsequent calls.
     * Fires tick callback if set.
     */
    private void onTick()
    {
        if (_onTick != null)
        {
            _onTick.callback();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called once the timer has run for the specified _duration.
     * If the _duration was set as infinity, then this method is never called.
     * Fires finished callback if set.
     */
    protected void onFinish()
    {
        if (_onFinish != null)
        {
            _onFinish.callback();
        }

        _isRunning = false;
    }

    /**
     * Stops the timer. If the timer is not running, then this call does nothing.
     */
    public void cancel()
    {
        pause();
        _elapsedTime = 0;
    }




    /// GETTERS



    /**
     * @return the elapsed time (in millis) since the start of the timer.
     */
    public long getElapsedTime()
    {
        return _elapsedTime;
    }

    /**
     * @return the time remaining (in millis) for the timer to stop.
     * If the _duration was set to {@code Timer#DURATION_INFINITY}, then -1 is returned.
     */
    public long getRemainingTime()
    {
        if (_duration <= PausableTimer.DURATION_INFINITY)
        {
            return PausableTimer.DURATION_INFINITY;
        }

        return _duration - _elapsedTime;
    }






    /// BINDERS



    /**
     * @return true if the timer is currently running, and false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isRunning()
    {
        return _isRunning;
    }

    /**
     * Binds onTick callback.
     */
    public void bindOnTick(Callbacks.VoidCallback callback)
    {
        _onTick = callback;
    }

    /**
     * Binds onFinish callback.
     * @param callback
     */
    public void bindOnFinish(Callbacks.VoidCallback callback)
    {
        _onFinish = callback;
    }
}
```

Here is a typical log. Basically what is happening is I start it up, wait 10-15 seconds, then start it again. It is supposed to fire every second. However it fires once or twice, then doesn't fire until its restarted.

> D/Timer: Reset timer
>
> D/Timer: Starting execution
>
> D/Timer: Fire
>
> D/Timer: Reset timer
>
> D/Timer: Starting execution
>
> D/Timer: Fire
>
> D/Timer: Fire
>
> D/Timer: Reset timer
>
> D/Timer: Starting execution

To be extra clear, here is some invoking code I use:

```
private void restartTimer()
{
    if (_timer != null)
    {
        _timer.cancel();
    }
    Log.d("Timer", "Reset timer");

    _timer = new PausableTimer(1000, PausableTimer.DURATION_INFINITY);
    _timer.bindOnTick(new Callbacks.VoidCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void callback()
        {
            decrementTimeRemaining();
        }
    });
    _timer.start();
}
```

**SOLUTION**

After figuring out that the `onTick()` call in my `run()` was causing the thread to get stopped, I solved this by dispatching the `onTick()` call to the main thread:

```
     _future = _execService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Log.d("Timer", "Run begin");

            Runnable task = new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    Log.d("Timer", "Main thread tick");
                    PausableTimer.this.onTick();
                }
            };
            Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            mainHandler.post(task);

            _elapsedTime += PausableTimer.this._interval;
            Log.d("Timer", "Run middle");


            // If time has exceeded duration, stop timer
            if (_duration > 0 && _elapsedTime >= _duration)
            {
                Log.d("Timer", "Finish");
                onFinish();
                _future.cancel(false);
            }
        }
    }, 0, PausableTimer.this._interval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: If it hasn't ended, then maybe this could prevent the JVM from spawning a new thread.  Why hasn't it finished?

Comment: Check that no exception is thrown in `onFinish` or other parts of the runnable.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at this when I'm back at the office!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm not sure why it's not firing the on finish. I am going to dig in now but this is what is making me scratch my head.

I will post my entire code now as it seems the shortened relevant snippet is not doing justice.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think your thread spawning issue might be in line with the issue I seemed to isolate. Take a look at my answer, I'd love your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting cause of the problem (to me at least).

This issue was my `onTick()` callback that I was firing:

I noticed something very odd with my logs. The `run()` logs before the `onTick()` were firing, and the ones below it where not:

```
    Log.d("Timer", "Starting execution");
    _future = _execService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Log.d("Timer", "Run begin"); // fires 

            onTick(); // when I remove this, all below logs fire!

            _elapsedTime += PausableTimer.this._interval;
            Log.d("Timer", "Run middle"); // didn't fire
            Log.d("Timer", "Elapsed time " + _elapsedTime); // didn't fire
            Log.d("Timer", "Duration " + _duration); // didn't fire

            // If time has exceeded duration, stop timer
            if (_duration > 0 && _elapsedTime >= _duration)
            {
                Log.d("Timer", "Finish"); // didn't fire
                onFinish();
                _future.cancel(false);
            }

            Log.d("Timer", "Run End"); // didn't fire
        }
    }, 0, PausableTimer.this._interval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

When I removed the `onTick()` all the logs fired.

I suspect something gets mucked up when I try to go on the main thread from here with the `onTick()`.

I'm not exactly sure yet, but this is the reason that the timer was only firing once, the `onTick()` call mucks it up.

I will continue to investigate further and am open to input you might have on this.

**Solution**
Dispatched the callback on the main thread:

```
    _future = _execService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Log.d("Timer", "Run begin");

            Runnable task = new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    Log.d("Timer", "Main thread tick");
                    PausableTimer.this.onTick();
                }
            };
            Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            mainHandler.post(task);

            _elapsedTime += PausableTimer.this._interval;
            Log.d("Timer", "Run middle");


            // If time has exceeded duration, stop timer
            if (_duration > 0 && _elapsedTime >= _duration)
            {
                Log.d("Timer", "Finish");
                onFinish();
                _future.cancel(false);
            }
        }
    }, 0, PausableTimer.this._interval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You set `_isRunning = true;` and never reset this to `false`;

2) Where are you setting `_duration`?  If this is `0`, your timer will never finish.

3) You're using `_interval` and `PausableTimer.this._interval`: do you mean to do that?

Comment: 1) Yea I wanted to focus this on the `run` of the service, it is set to false on finish

2) Its set to -1 which is infinity I believe

3) You are correct, I set to that explicitly as well to make sure but it didn't change anything

The timer still fires once or twice, and never fires the the `onFinish`.